# How to clear woocommerce cart using wp cli when user not logged in?

Tags: woocommerce

From within wp cli I can run any php, but I'm not logged in as a user just to call `wc_empty_cart()`;

In other words, how can I clear a woocommerce cart having been given user ID and not having this user logged in currently?